# Atmosphere appears on the dark side

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, light

This didn't used to happen but it seems like a bug I'm not sure. I was messing around with the color ramp of the atmosphere and now part of it appears on the dark side and then cuts off. I haven't changed anything like the emission of the sphere, just the color.

[image]

You can see that the atmosphere disappears where it transitions from day to night but then reappears with a sharp stop. At first I thought it was due to the spheres meeting points but I then moved the camera so that it would render along the side of the sphere (the render below) but it still does it.

Here's my node set up for the atmosphere. Everything in the right panel is the same as it was before.

[image]

Here's my blend file. Not sure how it'll look without the textures.
[Earth](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36713)

Comment: I assume you are still using BI (I added the tag for you this time, but in the future it would be a great help if you could do this :). Is it possible you could add a .blend or screenshots of your node setup? It's hard to debug a material with actually seeing the material..

Comment: Thank you for changing it, and I've added a screenshot of the node set up.

Comment: Hm.. I don't see anything obviously amiss, is it possible you could upload a demo.blend?

Comment: Sure, it won't come with the textures obviously as they're over 2gb each haha. The mesh you'll want to look at is called Soft Edge. I'll put it up in 10 minutes.

Comment: I had a look, but I haven't found anything yet. I guess that bit is not in the shadow of the solid earth sphere (the atmosphere etc. spheres are transparent and appear to be letting light through). Yet you say it worked before.. Is it possible something else was changed (besides the color ramp)?

Comment: No not at all. I put the project on halt for a month or 2 as I was (then) happy with the result as I had finally got the atmosphere to vanish on the dark side. I returned and rendered it, the same result, but I wasn't happy with how thick and prominent it was so I just tweaked the color ramp and then that happened so I came here haha. I find the sudden sharp stop to be more interesting. Haven't a clue how that happened.